# Trying to call a function

Tags: c++, struct, linked-list

So I'm trying to call this function but not too familiar with dynamic data structures and linked lists so I keep getting it wrong. This is my code so far:

```
struct Country
 {
  string  name;
  double  population;
 };
struct Node 
 {
  Country ctry;
  Node *  next;
 };
Node * world;

void push(Country data, Node * & list);

int main ()
{
    Country data;
    Node list;

    push(data, list);
    return 0;
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Where is the definition for push?

Comment: push() takes a reference to a pointer (for the 2nd parameter). You're passing an object, instead of a reference to a pointer.

Comment: push (data, &list) to convert it into a pointer.

Comment: @Mike: That won't work, either, because `&list` is a temporary pointer, and you can't bind a temporary to a non-const reference. So either remove the reference from the parameter, or else declare a `Node*` variable that points at the `list` variable and then pass the `Node*` variable to the parameter.

Answer (score 0):

The `push` function takes a `Node*&`, which is a "reference to a pointer to a Node" (always read the type backwards, it helps. You are giving it `list`, which is a `Node`. The function gets the reference from that call, but you said you would give a reference to a pointer to a Node, so you want to make `list` in `main` a `Node*` and allocate and initialize memory for it, or you want to make another variable that is a `Node*` and point it to `list` (`Node* ptr = &list;`). The first option would be preferable in most cases.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for comment guys, I changed my code to this and it works now

```
struct Country
 {
  string  name;
  double  population;
 };
struct Node 
 {
  Country ctry;
  Node *  next;
 };
Node * world;

void push(Country data, Node * & world);

int main ()
{
    Country data;

    push(data, world);
    return 0;
}
```